# C# WebBrowser control problem

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm using the webBrowser control to surf to a page that has an Iframe. 
I access the Iframe object like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["IFrameName"]
```

The problem is that sometimes the Frames collection has no frames and sometimes it does.

What might be the reason that the same exact code one time works fine and i get the iframe and few minutes later it's throwing an exception because the frame is not there?

Comment: Is the page fully loaded each time you query the frames collection?  Any post backs?

Comment: Yes. it's fully loaded. i have a "Wait()" function that waits 10 seconds before trying to get the iframe object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT what point are u making the call to the Frames collection? Are you doing this after the DocumentCompleted event?

That could make a difference ... you could handle the documentcompleted event and only make the call after the document has loaded.